# How to iterate attributes in custom direction's link method in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I use AngularJS custom directive which creates HTML element and want to add attributes, entered from HTML page, in 'link' method but i cannot iterate attributes. My code:

```
 link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
     // iterate attrs
 }
```

Is there way to iterate all attributes?

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.forEach(attrs, function(value, key) {
    ...some code here
}
```